# excel vba DO UNTIL and IF, to compare string cells

Tags: excel, vba

Sub comparison()
j = 0

```
    For i = 0 To 1109
        Do Until Cells(2 + i, 3) = Cells(2 + j, 12)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    
        If Cells(2 + i, 4) = Cells(2 + j, 13) Then
            Cells(2 + j, 16) = "OK"
        End If
    
        i = 0
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

I would like to write an "OK" if the cells in columns `D` and `M` are identical (instruction with `If`), only if the related name in columns `C` and `L` are identical (instruction with `Do Until`). So I want to do a comparison.
But the name in the cells (inside `Do Until` loop) are formed by string of words. And Excel gives me an error related to the sentence of `DO UNTIL`.
Could you help me?

### Update:

Here is some sample data:

[image]

THIS IS WHAT I WOULD FINALLY WANT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Todqu.png)

FOR SAME CELLS NAME (columns A and J),look at values of condition 1 (columns B and K) for each matching that is found and so finally written in column P ( and arrow equal to the one of the matching in MODEL 2) or OK (if values of cond1 are identical) or NO (if values od cond1 are different)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info.  Would you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37838038/edit) to include the error message?  I can see off-hand that you shouldn't be changing `i` anywhere inside your `For` loop.  I think you wanted `j=j+1` in the `Do Until` loop, and I think you can remove the `i=0` at the end of the `For` loop.

Comment: To add onto what @cxw said, right now you have an infinite loop since each time your run through your `For` loop `i` is set back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if you wish to compare row by row the columns `D`/`M` and `C`/`L` or if you are truly trying to compare all rows with all. Hence, I adjusted your code for both cases:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ComparisonRowByRow()

Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To 1109
        If .Cells(2 + i, 3).Value2 = .Cells(2 + i, 12).Value2 And _
            .Cells(2 + i, 4).Value2 = .Cells(2 + i, 13).Value2 Then
                .Cells(2 + i, 16).Value2 = "OK"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CompareAllWithAll()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    For i = 0 To 1109
        .Cells(2 + i, 16).ClearContents
        For j = 2 To lngLastRow
            If .Cells(2 + i, 3).Value2 = .Cells(2 + j, 12).Value2 And _
                .Cells(2 + i, 4).Value2 = .Cells(2 + j, 13).Value2 Then
                    If .Cells(2 + i, 16).Value2 = vbNullString Then
                        .Cells(2 + i, 16).Value2 = "OK, match found in row " & j
                    Else
                        .Cells(2 + i, 16).Value2 = .Cells(2 + i, 16).Value2 & ", " & j
                    End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

If you really wish to compare all rows with all then it is probably also of importance, where a matching row has been found. Hence, I added that to the code to log the matches.

Keep in mind that the second `sub` is rather time consuming at the moment. If you have 1,109 rows then the code will run 1,109 * 1,109 times. That would equate to a little over 1.2 million iterations: comparing D2 with M2, M3, M4, M5, ... M1109, comparing D3 with M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, ... M1109, etc.

To make this process faster I turned off `ScreenUpdating`, `Events`, and `Calculation`. Yet, there is a better / faster way with `arrays`. But I am not quite sure if you are familiar with arrays, therefore I kept your original coding. After all, we're trying to help you with **your** code (which you will have to update and maintain in the future).

Comment: thank you, but it is not the answer to my problem. I need two indicators because the cells are in different orders inside the columns, so I need them to navigate in them to select the cells with the same name (in do until loop) and then to compare with if cycle if the other cells are identical and so write OK. could you think again about the answer?

Comment: This is exactly what the second `sub` does. Compare all to all. Except that there is no "navigation" in the code. Yet, the results are logged in column 16 (which is column P). You might want to check again the answer(s). Otherwise, please try to clarify a bit more (possibly with sample data and a screenshot of what the current data looks like and a mock-up of your final result).

Comment: first of all , the cells, Cells(2 + i, 3) = Cells(2 + j, 12)
are composed by letters and numbers, is OK?

Comment: the second sub, I have tried right now, doesn't work, I mean NO outlet message and no words as results!

Comment: `the cells, Cells(2 + i, 3) = Cells(2 + j, 12) are composed by letters and numbers, is OK?` Yes.

Comment: `the second sub, ... doesn't work` In that case please elaborate on your post as described above: include sample data, a screenshot of your current sheet, and a screenshot of the result (you are aiming for).

Comment: I inserr the photo of my example

Comment: The above code works flawlessly on the sample data you provided. Apparently, you have some cells which do not contain "comparable" data. For example, if some cells show something like `#DIV/0!` or any other error then the above code will throw an error. Yet, since the provided data is without flaws, it works as intended.

Comment: Here is an Excel file with your sample data and the above code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzxpicwzrmj9gcy/StackOverflow_Question_37838038.xlsm?dl=0 You can verify that the code works correctly. This comment and the file will be removed within the next few days.

Comment: I want that macro find the arrow where the name of cell in column J is identical to a cell of column A. after that if also, the value of the cell of column K (of the same arrow) is identical to the value of cell in column B of the other arrow where it is found the match, hence write OK in column P and in the same arrow of the match cell found of column J.

Comment: for example, in my screenshot, only in P4 and in P5 macro has to write OK, because it saw that the values of cell K4 is identical (=5) to the value of colum B, where it is found the match of the same name of cells of columns J and A (in fact cells with name A- 1 S10 SX have cond1 equal to 5). the same for the other OK.

Comment: You have all the code you asked for and even got a working solution (with sample data you provided). If you still have questions then you will probably have to face the fact that you require paid help. Here are some sites you might want to check out: https://www.freelancer.com/work/freelance-excel-vba/1/ or https://www.upwork.com/o/jobs/browse/skill/vba/ or http://www.guru.com/d/freelancers/q/vba/

Comment: NO, your code is not working because it fails putting "OK,match found in row 2" in the wrong arrow, as I told you in the comment above

Comment: Once again, you should get some help because you (obviously) don't understand **YOUR** original code and what `OK, match found in row 2` means. It means that "for the items in column `C`/`D` a match has been found in row 2 (for columns `L`/`M`). I don't know why you wrote your code like this. I just left it as it was. So, since in row 3 columns `C`/`D` correspond to row 2 in columns `L`/`M` you see in row 3 a reference to row 2. That's your original code and what you asked for.

Comment: Maybe you want to change `.Cells(i, 16).Value2 = "OK, match found in row " & j` to `.Cells(i, 6).Value2 = "OK, match found in row " & j` to make your code clearer to yourself. Maybe you'd prefer `.Cells(j, 16).Value2 = "OK, match found in row " & i`? I don't know. That's for you to decide. But you can only do so if you actually understand what the code does. Clearly that's not the case. Therefore, I recommended above to get some professional help. The code works. What **you** want in the end if for **you** to adjust in **your** code (your requirements and your initial code).

Comment: I updated my first question with new image with the final result that I desider, I explain all what I want.

Comment: why if I substitute same values in the columns, the macro not detect all the same match but only the first and then it stops?